# Islamic Dressing of Males

Tags: sharia, clothing, awrah

It has been my question since long time that if a boy or a man is wearing T-shirts and loose pants (somehow considered permissible in Islam) and a girl passing by notices him; Is it a sin for a man? As one is not permitted to attract the opposite gender.

And should he wear a full sleeved shirt and cover the whole body such that he wouldn't be noticed by a girl or other women? Or is it natural regardless of the dress (being noticed by opposite gender)?

As far as Islam is concerned, Allah (SWT) prohibits women to make a dazzling display; Is it same for men? What is the dress of modesty nowadays?? Does T-shirts or half sleeves come under the same?

Also the arwah *(Satrr)* of male is from navel down to the knee; So, Is it fine for a male to show his chest and other parts that doesn't come in arwah?

Comment: There are two opinions one saying the 'awrah for a man is from navel to the knee, some say it is less and one could show his thighs (or at least parts of them).

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/are-tucked-in-shirts-and-pants-non-islamic

Answer (score 5):

Basically in jurisprudence we are concerned with a part by the name of Judgments on  Velation or Hijab of men. There we have Questions on: what are duties of men in front of unintimated women In  the subject of Hijab.
 Therefore first point is that In Islam religion we have duties for men in this occasion.

Second point is that what is here important and basic is intention. Basically if a man intends to fall women into  illegal action by wearing, it is illegal. Therefore intention of a man has importance in legality or illegality of an action. According to this, some jurist say that it is better that men wear those parts of body which is wore in common. Of course if men were aware of women's pleasuring, then they have to wear those parts.

Therefore if a male intent to show his chest to fall into illegal action , then this is forbidden.

See:

Tozih al Masael of Imam Khomeini the late, Ayatollah Sistani, Ayatollah Makarem shirazi, Imam Khamenei