# Are tucked-in shirts and pants non-Islamic?

Tags: halal-haram, men, modesty, awrah

It is a fact that Islam lays great emphasis on modesty just like Judaism and other orthodox religions. But why do we as Muslims enforce it mostly on women?

Men also have to cover their awrah which is what is between the navel and knees. But we see so many men and young teens nowadays who feel it is perfectly fine showing off the skin below the belly button while topless.

Also men are not suppose to wear tight fitting clothes exposing the shape of their awrah. If so then isn't it wrong when we tuck in the shirts to show the stomach and butts shape? Isn't the kurta or a long shirt or the kandura/toupe better for Muslim men?

**Related Questions of Interest:** 
1) [Are men who go topless sinners?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36306/are-men-who-go-topless-sinners) 
2) [Is man torso/chest/trunk awrah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/is-man-torso-chest-trunk-awrah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, awrah for men should be covered.

The same rules apply (**loose, opaque, non-conforming to other religions** e.g. a t-shirt with a cross on it isn't acceptable). *A combination of bias and ignorance are possible reasons for why this isn't happening.*

I haven't heard people complain about **football uniforms** even though they **clearly violate these guidelines**.

For reference:

● avoiding other religions' symbols: -

> أن النبيَّ صلَّى اللهُ عليه وسلَّم لم يكن يترُكُ في بيتهِ شيئًا فيه
>   تَصاليبُ إلا نَقضهُ .         الراوي:     عائشة أم المؤمنين   المحدث:
>         البخاري  - المصدر: صحيح البخار ي- الصفحة أو الرقم: 5952خلاصة حكم
>   المحدث: [صحيح]
>
> I never used to leave in the Prophet (ﷺ) house anything carrying images or crosses but he obliterated it.

Another hadith is 2077 of Sahih Muslim.
● Silk : Sahih al-Bukhari 5801 
 ●Effeminate dress: Sahih Al-Bukhari 5885
●arrogance/excess: al-nisai 2559, albukhari 3465. 
 (previous points not mentioned earlier but still relevant).
 As for opaque, see through clothing and tight clothing, they defeat the purpose of clothing as stated in [al aaraf:26](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/7/26).

Comment: Sure. Here's bullet points: ● avoiding other religions' symbols:﻿ - أن النبيَّ صلَّى اللهُ عليه وسلَّم لم يكن يترُكُ في بيتهِ شيئًا فيه تَصاليبُ إلا نَقضهُ .    الراوي:  عائشة أم المؤمنين  المحدث:   البخاري  - المصدر: صحيح البخار ي- الصفحة أو الرقم: 5952خلاصة حكم المحدث: [صحيح] .I never used to leave in the Prophet (ﷺ) house anything carrying images or crosses but he obliterated it. Another hadith is 2077 of Sahih Muslim.

Comment: ● Silk : Sahih al-Bukhari 5801 // ●Effeminate dress: Sahih Al-Bukhari 5885//●arrogance/excess: al-nisai 2559, albukhari 3465.  // (previous points not mentioned earlier but still relevant). // as for opaque, see through clothing and tight clothing defeat the purpose of clothing as stated in al aaraf:26.

Comment: @medi1saif n00b here, I'm on it.