# Are men who go topless sinners?

Tags: halal-haram, men, awrah

I read that the 'awrah' for males in Islam is from the belly button to the knees.

If true, do men who go topless these days with just their jeans/pants/shorts exposing their awrah as the lower grament tends to start usually just above the buttocks?

Comment: Maybe these two fatwas answer your question https://islamqa.info/en/171584 and https://islamqa.info/en/34976

Comment: Also relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/is-man-torso-chest-trunk-awrah