# 'Awrah for men in Islam

Tags: men, awrah

Is it permissible to wear shorts which are just above the knees? Because as per my understanding, a man's pardah is from the navel to the knees.

Comment: There's no hijab for men but you maybe referring to 'awrah. And the 'awrah of men is well discussed scholars hold different opinions whether it is allowed to disclose the body from thigh downwards or from above or below the knee downwards and all of them have their evidences. We are not here to discuss which of these opinions is more correct.

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36306/are-men-who-go-topless-sinners

Answer (score 0):

The Knee is included in the *'awrah* according to some madhabs and so should be covered according to them.